# Adjust width in Leaflet Popup to fit loaded content

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, leaflet, components

Inside my Ionic page, I load leaflet map and set another standalone component as popup for some marker, because I need data as @Input inside this popup. This is working so far correctly. The strange thing is, when the popup opens the first time, the size is too small for it content, so elements are overlapping. After closing and reopening the popup, everything is how it should be.

[image: Here the popup is to small for it's content]
[image: How the popup looks after the second time opening]

This is how I load the Popup inside my map page:

```
constructor(
 private injector: Injector
 private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
) {}

component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopupComponent).create(this.injector);
```

Method to load marker:

```
L.marker([marker.latitude, marker.longitude], {icon: this.evcsIcon})
      .bindPopup(this.component.location.nativeElement)
      .on('click', () => this.setPopupConfig(marker));
```

To use @Input in my Popup-Component, I use the following:

```
setPopupConfig(marker: any) {
    this.component.instance.marker = marker;
    this.component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

My Popup component is quite simple:

```
<div style="background-color: red">
    <ion-button>Reservieren</ion-button>
    <ion-button>Navigieren</ion-button>
</div>
```

I tried to set the width of the div inside popup-component, but nothing worked so far.

**EDIT**

Maybe some additional information is needed. When I load the map, I also call a method, which centers the popup when opening:

```
centerMarker() {
    //center marker when popup opens
    this.map.on('popupopen', (e: any) => {
      var px = this.map!.project(e.target._popup._latlng); // find the pixel location on the map where the popup anchor is
      px.y -= e.target._popup._container.clientHeight / 2; // find the height of the popup container, divide by 2, subtract from the Y axis of marker location
      this.map!.panTo(this.map!.unproject(px), { animate: true }); // pan to new center
    });
  }
```

Comment: See the `update` method at https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-method

Comment: @IvanSanchez I looked at it, but I'm not able to use it correctly. I tried to save my marker with `const test= L.marker(...).bindPopup(...).on('click', () => this.setPopupConfig(marker,test) ` and added in `setPopupConfig()` as last line `test.getPopup()?.update();`

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue to me. Maybe, you need to reserve some space using `min-width: 100px` or something. Why don't you check the CSS properties of the popup, see what changed on the 2nd time it opened compared to the first time it opened?

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 I did not style anything and can't see any relevant changes in CSS after 2nd time. Normally, a div is as large as its content. I can't set the min-width because on mobile devices I need the popup to cover almost the whole screen and on desktop to cover up like 10 percent of the screen. I search for a cleaner solution than working with breakpoints and setting for each the width ...

Comment: As current workaround, I insert `<a style="visibility: hidden; font-size: xx-small">TTT...</a>` and add as many 'T's as I need to increase the popup width. But that's far away from a good solution :D

Comment: Okay. Maybe you can also use `:after` pseudo selector with `content: &nbsp;` to increase the width. This isn't much different from the one you did. Here, we don't use any visible characters and it wouldn't affect the accessibility also.